# how to connect MongoDB in Cloud9?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, cloud9-ide

I have a problem with the connection database MongoDB in Cloud9
Please help to resolve this issue!

```
var MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
var port = process.env.PORT;
var ip   = process.env.IP;
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://"+ip+":"+port+"/test",function(error,db){
        if(!error){
         console.log("We are connected");   
        }
        else{
         console.dir(error); //failed to connect to [127.4.68.129:8080]               
        }
});
```

Output:

```
Running Node Process
Your code is running at 'http://demo-project.alfared1991.c9.io'.
Important: use 'process.env.PORT' as the port and 'process.env.IP' as the host in your scripts!
[Error: failed to connect to [127.4.68.129:8080]]
```

Comment: I think @alfared was asking about how to connect to the local mongodb instance in Cloud9 and was not properly answered. I tried to edit the question but the edit was not approved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`process.env.PORT` and `process.env.IP` are the port and IP address for your application, not your database. You'll want to pull your Mongo connection string from your MongoDB provider.

Below is the hello world example from the [Node.js homepage](http://nodejs.org/) modified to use the two environment variables.

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(process.env.PORT || 1337, process.env.IP || '127.0.0.1');
```

Comment: And there are some concrete examples?
I mean, I first need to create / run a web server? I do not understand

Answer (score 7):

If you follow https://docs.c9.io/setting_up_mongodb.html this link, you will setup and run your mongodb daemon under your workspace.

And if you take a look at the output of `./mongod`, you'll find out this output:

```
2015-08-22T12:46:47.120+0000 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=7699 port=27017 dbpath=data 64-bit host=velvetdeth-express-example-1804858
```

Just copy the host and port value to your mongodb config, set up the database url, in this case is:

```
mongodb://velvetdeth-express-example-1804858:27017
```

Comment: For me, using mongoose, this worked, but I had to add the database name: `mongodb://velvetdeth-express-example-1804858:27017/mydata`

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who runs into this issue, the solution is here: https://docs.c9.io/setting_up_mongodb.html

MongoDB is preinstalled in the Cloud9 workspace. Run this:

```
$ mkdir data
$ echo 'mongod --bind_ip=$IP --dbpath=data --nojournal --rest "$@"' > mongod
$ chmod a+x mongod
```

To start the Mongodb process, run:

```
$ ./mongod
```

Then 'run' your node.js app script and you're off to the races.

Here's what the parameters mean:

> --dbpath=data (because it defaults to /var/db which isn't accessible)
>
> --nojournal because mongodb usually pre-allocates 2 GB journal file (which exceeds Cloud9 disk space quota)
>
> --bind_ip=$IP (because you can't bind to 0.0.0.0)
>
> --rest runs on default port 28017

Comment: Do you know what connection string would you use to access the db in cloud9? The mongodb://localhost/dbname does not work there, and I tried 'mongodb://' + process.env.IP + '/dbname', also with no success.

Comment: I believe I used mongoose and the command line. I don't know that you can remotely access the database outside of cloud9. Otherwise you should just use 'localhost' as far as I recall. Sorry, I deleted this project so I don't have the code handy.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I want to use it within the application, but mongodb://localhost/dbname does not work.

Comment: @LucasReis I actually found my source archive on Bitbucket, and I was using the MEAN stack. In addition to the ./mongod file I mentioned above, I also had in my express.js: 'var mongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session)' and then later in the file, // Express/Mongo session storage
  app.use(session({
    secret: config.sessionSecret,
    store: new mongoStore({
      db: db.connection.db,
      collection: config.sessionCollection
    }),
    cookie: config.sessionCookie,
    name: config.sessionName,
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
  }));' - hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot @James Gentes! As soon as I can I'll try comparing the configs.